# Is there a way to pass CSS class in isolated mode?

Tags: c#, css, blazor, isolation

Let's say I am building composite component, and part of it is:

```
  <InputNumber class="testing" ...
```

When "testing" is global CSS class name it works fine, but if it is local to my component, because of CSS isolation it won't work.

So my question is -- is there a way to make the second scenario work too? I.e. keep CSS class definition local (isolated) and yet pass to child component? In "extreme" case is there a way to share it -- that is, use this class both in my component and in child one as well?

Comment: Check out the :deep attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you put a `<div>` around it and add `::deep` to the style:

#### MyComponent.razor

```
<div>
 
  ...
  <InputNumber class="testing" ... />

</div
```

#### MyComponent.razor.css

```css
::deep .testing {
  ...
}
```

but i have no clue as to why the `<div>` is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested `div`, `span`, and then without additional element. It works in all those cases.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work w/o the div, I'll look into that later.

Comment: That's been my experience, too: that outer div is absolutely required.  I suppose without it, there's nothing to attach the Css key id to.

Comment: @greenoldman post an outline of your component, I guess there is an outer div there.

Comment: @HH, my mistake, I thought this wrapping element is needed for this particular component. In general sense yes, I have outer `div` for entire Blazor page. I am sorry for the confusion.